# delete only text in a row (but not the row) when delete button is tapped in editing mode of UITABLEVIEW

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editing

I have changed the delete button title to "Clear" in UItableView's editing mode. Now, tapping on this button just clears the text in this cell. But after clearing the delete button doesnot go back and the '-' button also doesnot rotates to original position. Please suggest some workaround and solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who had taken time to think on this problem. I got the solution. I called `[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:editedIndexPathsArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom]`. Worked like a charm. Also, animation came with it like a bonus. Moreover, I was doing [tableView reloadData], but there was no need to reload whole tableView just for a 2-3 rows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you call `[tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want my table view to remain in edited mode always